# Populate Single Input From Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to populate three or an input using three or more select. but it does paste the value from first two select and ignoring the third one.

Html

```
    <select id="field1" class="required" size="0">
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>
        <option value="Four">Four</option>
    </select>
    <select id="field2" class="required" size="0">
        <option value="Eggs">Eggs</option>
        <option value="Shake">Shakes</option>
        <option value="Drink">Drinks</option>
    </select>


    <select id="field3" class="required" size="0">
        <option value="Billed">Billed</option>
        <option value="Unpaid">Unpaid</option>
        <option value="Service">Service</option>
    </select>
    <input name="tistle" type="text" id="inputter" value="">
```

JS

```
    var selectedField1 = "";
    jQuery('#field1').on('change', function () {
        jQuery("#inputter").val(jQuery("#field1").val());
        selectedField1 = jQuery("#field1").val();
    });

    jQuery('#field2').on('change', function () {
        var valuetwo = selectedField1
        jQuery("#inputter").val(valuetwo + ' ' + jQuery("#field2").val());
    });

    jQuery('#field3').on('change', function () {
        var valuethree = selectedField1 + valuetwo
        jQuery("#inputter").val(valuethree + jQuery("#field3").val());
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vr3mv9n8/

Is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code about the third select is due to the reference to the *valuetwo* variable, which is out of scope. In other words, *valuetwo* doesn't exist out of the `jQuery('#field2').on(...)` fragment (remember that JavaScript's variables have function scope).

The other two selects work because selectedField1 is defined out of the `.on()` function (similar to a global variable). I've modified a bit your code to show you the behavior:

```
    var selectedField1 = "";
    var valuetwo = '';
    var valuethree = '';

    jQuery('#field1').on('change', function () {
        jQuery("#inputter").val(jQuery("#field1").val());
        selectedField1 = jQuery("#field1").val();
    });

    jQuery('#field2').on('change', function () {
        valuetwo = jQuery("#field2").val();
        jQuery("#inputter").val(selectedField1 + ' ' + valuetwo);
    });

    jQuery('#field3').on('change', function () {
        valuethree = jQuery("#field3").val();
        jQuery("#inputter").val(selectedField1 + ' ' + valuetwo + ' ' + valuethree);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `valuetwo` within the third function since it is local to the second function. Also you assign first value into `valuetwo` and then in 3rd one you repeat the first value twice. Check the updated code.

```js
var selectedField1 = "";
var valueone = "";
var valuetwo = "";
var valuethree = "";
    jQuery('#field1').on('change', function () {
        valueone = jQuery("#field1").val();
        jQuery("#inputter").val(valueone + ' ' + valuetwo + ' ' + valuethree);
    });

    jQuery('#field2').on('change', function () {
        valuetwo = jQuery("#field2").val();
        jQuery("#inputter").val(valueone + ' ' + valuetwo + ' ' + valuethree);
    });

    jQuery('#field3').on('change', function () {
        valuethree = jQuery("#field3").val();
        jQuery("#inputter").val(valueone + ' ' + valuetwo + ' ' + valuethree);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field1" class="required" size="0">
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>
        <option value="Four">Four</option>
    </select>
    <select id="field2" class="required" size="0">
        <option value="Eggs">Eggs</option>
        <option value="Shake">Shakes</option>
        <option value="Drink">Drinks</option>
    </select>


    <select id="field3" class="required" size="0">
        <option value="Billed">Billed</option>
        <option value="Unpaid">Unpaid</option>
        <option value="Service">Service</option>
    </select>
    <input name="tistle" type="text" id="inputter" value="">
```

Comment: the only thing I would change is set all three options on all 3 inputs, `.value` will be an empty string so it won't get in the way, and your current solution is awkward if the user changes their mind for option 1 or 2